# Integrated webcam works sometimes in Google Meet but not in Cheese [Razor Blade]

Tags: usb, webcam

I have been having this weird issue. When I go to [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com/) I'm able to turn my webcam (sometimes). When I'm not able to make the webcam work the webcam light keeps flickering (keep turning on and off) but no image shows up on Google Meet. I have noticed that usually, I'm able to use the webcam after restarting my computer but only for a limited time. Whenever I open cheese I get the following:

```
(cheese:125582): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:33:13.142: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:125582): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 21:33:13.142: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:125582): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:33:13.142: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
```

Trying with guvcview the same happens (no image whatsoever). The cameras are being listed

*ls /dev/video**

```
/dev/video0
/dev/video1
```

*lsusb*

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:0255 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Blade
Bus 001 Device 123: ID 13d3:56bd IMC Networks USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Doing *v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all* gives me

```
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : USB Camera: USB Camera
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-7
    Driver version   : 5.8.18
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : USB Camera: USB Camera
    Serial           : 0x0001
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-7
    Media version    : 5.8.18
    Hardware revision: 0x00002001 (8193)
    Driver version   : 5.8.18
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : USB Camera: USB Camera
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags         : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1280/720
    Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 1843200
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720, Flags: 
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720, Flags: 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-127 max=127 step=1 default=0 value=0
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=64 value=64
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-180 max=180 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=270 max=330 step=1 default=300 value=300
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=8 step=1 default=0 value=0
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1
                0: Disabled
                1: 50 Hz
                2: 60 Hz
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=10 default=4600 value=4600 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=2 step=1 default=0 value=0
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1
```

I have tried many solutions found on AskUbuntu, Ubuntu forums, and Reddit threads. None, unfortunately, seems to work. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use another USB port or cable? Looks like it's a hardware issue.

Comment: @ExploitFate it is an integrated webcam